# postgresql trigger on tsvector column get ERROR: column "does not exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

Here's my schema

```
          Column          |            Type            
--------------------------+----------------------------
 id                       | integer                    
 title                    | character varying(255)     
 summary                  | character varying(255)     
 readable_content         | text                       
 created_at               | timestamp without time zone
 updated_at               | timestamp without time zone
 textsearchable_index_col | tsvector                   

Indexes:
    "site_articles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_site_articles_on_textsearchable_index_col" gin (textsearchable_index_col)
Triggers:
    site_articles_before_insert_update_row_tr BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON site_articles FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE site_articles_before_insert_update_row_tr()
```

and here's the trigger function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION site_articles_before_insert_update_row_tr() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    new.tsv := tsvector_update_trigger(textsearchable_index_col, 'pg_catalog.simple', title, summary, readable_content);
    new.tsv := setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.simple', coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A') ||
                setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.simple', coalesce(new.summary,'')), 'B') ||
                setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.simple', coalesce(new.readable_content,'')), 'C');
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

However, when I update a record like this:

```sql
UPDATE "site_articles" SET "updated_at" = '2013-12-13 05:43:59.802580' WHERE "site_articles"."id" = 1
```

I get

```
ERROR:  column "textsearchable_index_col" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT tsvector_update_trigger(textsearchable_index_col, 'pg...
                                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT tsvector_update_trigger(textsearchable_index_col, 'pg_catalog.simple', title, summary, readable_content)
```

I'm pretty sure the column name is correct. Not sure if it matters, I concatenate the rows like this after I added the tsvector column (I'm using Rails migration)

```ruby
def up
  add_column :site_articles, :textsearchable_index_col, :tsvector

  sql = <<-SQL
    UPDATE site_articles SET textsearchable_index_col =
                   to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("site_articles"."title"::text,'')
                               || ' ' || coalesce("site_articles"."summary"::text, '')
                               || ' ' || coalesce("site_articles"."readable_content"::text, '')
                              );
  SQL
  execute sql

  add_index :site_articles, :textsearchable_index_col, using: 'gin'
end
```

Did I miss something or each column should have its own tsvector column (not concatenated in one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. It should be `new.textsearchable_index_col`. The same for subsequent fields.

(Btw, there's little point in assigning tsv twice. Either use your first (corrected) statement, or your second. But not both, since the second overrides the first, and a tsv is expensive to compute.)

Comment: Thanks Denis. I get this error

    ERROR:  function tsvector_update_trigger(tsvector, unknown, character varying, character varying, text) does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT tsvector_update_trigger(new.textsearchable_index_col,...
                   ^
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    QUERY:  SELECT tsvector_update_trigger(new.textsearchable_index_col, 'pg_catalog.simple', new.title, new.summary, new.readable_content)

Comment: Per the comment in my answer, you should remove one of the two queries. (Probably that one, too.) But id you insist on making it work, cast it per Postgres's request. Probably `'pg_catalog.simple'::text`.

Comment: And, by, readable_content should be weight D, and summary weight C. The docs highlight the convention: weight A for title, B for keywords, C for summary, and D for content,