# Rails Postgres error following migration: tsvector column does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I'm running Postgres version 9.3.4.2 with Rails. I migrated the database and removed the `tsvector` column from model `Post` (and added it to `Message`). Now when I hit the `create` action of the Post controller with an attempt to `INSERT INTO "posts"` I get an error saying `"tsvector column 'tsv_body' does not exist"`. The Schema shows no `tsvector` column for `posts`. I've restarted the server and Postgres. What's going on? I suppose technically the error message is correct - the `tsvector` column `tsv_body` doesn't exist! It isn't meant to. But why is it looking for a `tsvector` column in the `Post` model in the first place?

**EDIT**

Ok, I found this at the end of Railscasts ep. 343. I think the problem is caused by this code:

```
class AddTsvectorSearchToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    # Adds a tsvector column for the body
    add_column :posts, :tsv_body, :tsvector

    # Adds an index for this new column
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE INDEX index_posts_tsv_body ON posts USING gin(tsv_body);
    SQL

    # Updates existing rows so this new column gets calculated
    execute <<-SQL
      UPDATE posts SET tsv_body = (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(content, '')));
    SQL

    # Sets up a trigger to update this new column on inserts and updates
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
      ON posts FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
      tsvector_update_trigger(tsv_body, 'pg_catalog.english', content);
    SQL
  end
end
```

Apparently the `schema.rb` file is incomplete when there are sql migrations. So the question now becomes: How do you write a migration to undo this code?

Comment: can you check if it exists under your model using this command `Post.column_names`

Comment: `Post.column_names` matches up with the schema. There's no `tsvector` column.

Comment: And there are no `before_save` or `after_save` callbacks in the `Post` model.

Comment: Add the code that's breaking and the model `Post`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tsvector is a type of data in postgres, i.e. column type rather than column name and or also have to do with indexing. If you can post your code, people might be able to help. otherwise, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556255/postgresql-trigger-on-tsvector-column-get-error-column-does-not-exist?rq=1) might give you more clue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the schema file was incomplete. Turns out the correct database structure is shown in structure.sql. And indeed in there, there was `CREATE TRIGGER` code on the `Post` table. This migration fixed it:

```
def change
  execute <<-SQL
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_posts_tsv_body;
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tsvectorpostupdate ON posts;
  SQL
end
```